# How can I change my x-axis ticks to show every date on my x-axis in my chart?

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts, axis, bitcoin

I downloaded Bitcoin price data and I want to plot the results. This is my code to retrieve price data:

```
import requests
periods = '86400'

resp = requests.get('https://api.cryptowat.ch/markets/bitfinex/btcusd/ohlc', params={'periods': periods})

data = resp.json()
df = pd.DataFrame(data['result'][periods], columns=[
    'CloseTime', 'OpenPrice', 'HighPrice', 'LowPrice', 'ClosePrice', 'Volume', 'NA'])

df['CloseTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['CloseTime'], unit='s')
df.set_index('CloseTime', inplace=True)

#filter df by date until 1 month ago
df1 = df['2019-11-12':'2019-12-11']
price = df1[['ClosePrice']].copy()
```

My code for plotting my results looks like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

price['ClosePrice'].plot(figsize=(14, 7), color = 'blue')
plt.grid(b=True, which='both', color='#666666', linestyle='-')
plt.ylabel('Price')
plt.title('Bitcoin price')
```

For better visualization, it would be better if all dates are displayed on the x axis.

I tried `plt.xticks(price.index)`, but unfortunately that does not work. Can somebody help me out to show every date of the data frame on the x-axis?

The output of my code looks like the attached image.

[image]

Comment: If your matter is solved I suggest you mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
plt.xticks(price.index, price.index, rotation=45)
```

As per the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html) you can provide the index **and** the labels.

[image]

To display dates without time:

```
date_labels = price.index.map(lambda t: t.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
plt.xticks(price.index, labels = date_labels, rotation=45)
```

Comment: Is there a chance to only plot dates without the time?